# Likert package in R: Order of bars

Tags: r, plot

Using the following command, I am getting a nicely arranged plot in which the questions are sorted by the level of agreement.

```
likert_var <- likert(as.data.frame(results[,c("Abc", "Ced","Bcd")]))

plot(likert_var,ordered=TRUE)
```

However, I would like to display the items in the order provided, not necessarily alphabetical which happens if I set ordered to FALSE.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please produce a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610).

Comment: Here's a similar question. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415674/reordering-groups-in-likert-plots-with-r